# Oracle connect by level complication

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm having difficulties with a query that's purpose is to split a row into two.

My sample data:

```
       ID OLD                      NEW                    
---------- ------------------------ ------------------------
        12 L-D / T-E                L-E / T-E               
        13 L-D / T-E                L-D / T-D               
        14 L-D / T-E                L-E / T-D
```

Where the new and old values differ, I'd like to split them so my output should be:

```
id | OLD | NEW
12 | L-D | L-E  //in this instance T hasn't changed so I will ignore it.
13 | T-E | T-D  //similar to the above but this time only add T
14 | L-D | L-E  //both values have changed, two rows required
14 | T-E | T-D
```

I've put together a 'working' example but the results are duplicated.  I think the issue is with the connect by level, I'm quite new to Oracle so debugging is a touch difficult.

Any help is much appreciated.

This is the query I'm using to drop, create and run the query:

It runs fine in sqldeveloper but unsure if sqlplus will be impressed with it.

```
    drop table t;
CREATE TABLE T
    (id int, 
     old varchar2(24), 
     new varchar2(24))
;

INSERT ALL

      INTO T (id, old, new)
         VALUES (12, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-E / T-E')
      INTO T (id, old, new)
         VALUES (13, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-D / T-D')
      INTO T (id, old, new)
         VALUES (14, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-E / T-D')

SELECT * FROM dual
;


SELECT * FROM T;

--insert into t (id, old, new) values (1,'dasdsad', 'asdasd');

BEGIN
INSERT INTO t (id,old, new) 

  WITH DATA AS
      (SELECT id,OLD, new
      FROM t
      WHERE 
      --multiple changes
      (
        (SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) <> SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
        AND SUBSTR(OLD, 9)    <> SUBSTR(NEW, 9)
        )
      OR
        --row 2 old/new L are same, old/new T are not
        (SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) = SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
        AND SUBSTR(OLD, 9)    <> SUBSTR(NEW, 9)
        )

      OR
        --row 1
        (SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) <> SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
        AND SUBSTR(OLD, 9) = SUBSTR(NEW, 9)
        )

      )
      )

    SELECT id, trim(regexp_substr(OLD, '[^/]+', 1, LEVEL)) OLD,  
               trim(regexp_substr(NEW, '[^/]+', 1, LEVEL)) NEW
    FROM DATA
      CONNECT BY (LEVEL <= regexp_count(new, '/')+1);

END;
 /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use a recursive syntax.
First I would create virtual columns (or a view) to eliminate cumbersome `substring` functions from the query, in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD ( OLD_LEFT AS ( Substr( OLD, 1, 3 )));
ALTER TABLE t ADD ( OLD_RIGHT AS ( Substr( OLD, 7, 3 )));
ALTER TABLE t ADD ( NEW_LEFT AS ( Substr( NEW, 1, 3 )));
ALTER TABLE t ADD ( NEW_RIGHT AS ( Substr( NEW, 7, 3 )));
```

or:

```
CREATE VIEW tt AS
SELECT ID, OLD, NEW,
       Substr( OLD, 1, 3 ) As OLD_LEFT,
       Substr( OLD, 7, 3 ) As OLD_RIGHT,
       Substr( NEW, 1, 3 ) As NEW_LEFT,
       Substr( NEW, 7, 3 ) As NEW_RIGHT
FROM t;
```

---

After the above simplification, the query is very straightforward, just:

```
SELECT id, OLD_LEFT , NEW_LEFT 
FROM T
WHERE OLD_LEFT <> NEW_LEFT
UNION ALL
SELECT id, OLD_RIGHT , NEW_RIGHT 
FROM T
WHERE OLD_RIGHT <> NEW_RIGHT
ORDER BY ID
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2fdc4/2

Comment: speecless.  I spent several hours yesterday working on a solution, it works and does what it should but to then be able to simplify it lie this...damn. :)

Comment: my actual implementation with much uglier as well. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98774/oracle-query-to-split-1-row-into-two-where-conditions-are-applicable